# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

i am facing problem in inserting image inside db, error message is:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES('','$_59.jpg','����' at line 1

Query written is:

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES(id,name,image)VALUES('','$image_name','$image')") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

I am Using xamppv3.2.1, Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3, Server version: 5.6.21 - MySQL Community Server (GPL).

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 4):

You have an errant `VALUES` keyword:

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO store (id,name,image) VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

FYI, if your `id` column is set to auto-increment you don't need to have it in your query:

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO store (name,image) VALUES ('$image_name','$image')") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: i will keep dt in mind from next time. Does not using prepared statemnt causing this error? i hope not

Comment: This would have failed no matter what API you used for your database

Comment: but if i do not enter image which is a blob data type the database operation is working seamless. inserting blob type data is the problem.

Comment: You probably have an incorrect format for the blob. You may need to call file_get_contents() on it for it to work.

Comment: i am using the code $image=file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); for that i echoed $image its displaying image in binary form.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your query, you are using VALUES keyword incorrectly. Modify it to:

```
INSERT INTO store (id,name,image) VALUES('','$image_name','$image')
```

I doubt your id is VARCHAR type. If it is INT type, put some integer value there.

```
INSERT INTO store (id,name,image) VALUES(1,'$image_name','$image')
```

If your id is auto increment, let db insert it

```
INSERT INTO store (name,image) VALUES('$image_name','$image')
```

Comment: id is primary key its on auto increment and ofcors int. i tried doing it like "INSERT INTO store (name,image) VALUES('$image_name','$image')" no luck